# How can i have php execute change a html webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

So my setup is as follows:
I have html code with multiple forms however JavaScript hides all but the "login" form.
Upon submission I want php to validate the users input and if the input is valid i want javascript to display the previously hidden forms and hide the "login" form.

What would be the best way to do this?, thanks in advance :)

Also here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Encyrpion email</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#flip").click(function(){
            $("#panel").slideToggle("medium");
                });
            });
            document.getElementById('mail').style.display='none'
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function show(id){
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            }
            function hide(id){
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            }
        </script>
        <a href="#" onclick="show('mail'), hide('login'); return false;">Edit</a>
        <div id="login">
            <form id="login" method="post" action="login.php">
                <label for="Username">Username</label>
                <input class="input-hover-grey" type="text" name="Username" id="Username" required placeholder=""/>
                <label for="Password">Password</label>
                <input class="input-hover-grey" type="Password" name="Password" id="Password" required placeholder=""/>
                <input class="input-hover-grey" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>switch('login','mail')</script>
        <div id="mail" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <br>
                    <div id="flip">
                        <input class="input-hover-grey" value="More information" type="button">
                    </div>
                    <div id="panel">
                        <p>
                            This program allow you to encrypt and send messages trough a regualr email protocol.
                        </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <form method="post" action="verify.php">
                    <label for="message">Message</label><br>
                    <textarea class="input-hover-grey" name="message" id="message" rows="4"></textarea>
                    <label for="Key" type="small">Key</label><br>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="number" name="=Key" id="Key" required placeholder=""/>
                    <br>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="submit" name="submit" value="Encrypt">
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                </form>
                    <br>
                <form method="post" action="verify.php"> 
                    <label for="sender">Senders email adress</label>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="email" name="sender" id="sender" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/>
                    <label for="reciever">Recievers email adress</label>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="email" name="reciever" id="reciever" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/>
                    <label for="Subject">Subject</label>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="text" name="Subject" id="Subject" required placeholder=""/>
                    <p></p>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" align="left" data-sitekey="6Le3DicUAAAAAKo4tSQAL6yhsfSna_MbLwpR4T0s" required></div>
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                    <input class="input-hover-grey" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
        if ($_POST['Username'] != "User") {
        echo "Invalid username";
        exit;
        }
        elif ($_POST['Password'] != "12345") {
        echo "Invalid password";
        exit;
        }
        else:
?>
```

Comment: Remove all the JavaScript. Use PHP to decide which of two versions of the HTML document (logged in page / not logged in page) to output when the page is requested.

Comment: Either submit the login form to the same page and decide what section to show as @Quentin explained or you can use `ajax` to validated user using JS and then if user is authenticated hide login and show other forms.